# How to bind functional React component to class events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to wrap my head around functional components and binding.

If I have a functional React component that looks like this:

```
const Dashboard = props => {
    const _dashboard = new _Dashboard()

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="title">Dashboard</div>
            <button>Log</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And a class that looks like this:

```
class _Dashboard {
    constructor() { }

    log() {
        console.log('Dashboard Log Clicked!')
    }
}
```

What is the proper way to bind the button click?

This is what I tried and doesn't work

```
const Dashboard = props => {
    const _dashboard = new _Dashboard()

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="title">Dashboard</div>
            <button onClick={ _dashboard.log }>Log</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

but I feel like I'm missing something in the general way it works.

Edit: I removed the parenthesis from the log() call. Neither way is writing anything to the console.

Comment: could you check the value of your _dashboard in dev tools? (line:  <button onClick={ _dashboard.log }>Log</button> )

Comment: It doesn't even look like _dashboard is getting instantiated. adding `console.log('test')` to the _Dashboard class is never getting called

Comment: try this._dashboard?
also the console.log('test'); should IMO be on the componentWillMount() or componentDidMount() of the class if you want to see it.
Are you getting any console errors btw?

Comment: btw; try replacing your line: "<button onClick={ _dashboard.log }>Log</button>" with "<button onClick={ () => { console.log('test'); } }>Log</button>" . If that doesn't run, then your problem is a different one than binding the button onClick event correctly.

Comment: Ok, so looks like something else is going on, because `<button onClick={ () => { console.log('test'); } }>Log</button>` didn't do anything either. Back to the drawing board. Haha. The weirdest thing is there are no errors. Everything renders fine.

Comment: Checked your code in sandbox: http://www.react.run/E1UY8cAil/3 it works as expected. Probably your issue is not there.

Answer (score 1):

you are calling the `function aka _dashboard.log()` instead of `_dashboard.log ;`

Comment: & if you need to bind it to the button, you'd write ::_dashboard.log; or _dashboard.log.bind(this); (supposing for instance you need the value associated with that button).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the parenthesis otherwise you are actually invoking the function and binding `onClick` to the result of that function. Without parenthesis you pass a reference to the function.

```
<button onClick={_dashboard.log}>Log</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to write something like:

```
 <button onClick={_dashboard.log}>Log</button>
```

or

```
 <button onClick={() => _dashboard.log()}>Log</button>
```

otherwise your code will be executed immediatly and not bound.